# How to create a loop to run the same regression model for several independent variables

Tags: loops, model

I have to fit the same regression model for several dependent variables. I also have to assign a name to each model using the name of the dependent variable.

I tried to write a loop with the following code:

```
dep <- c('dlco', 'dlno', 'va', 'vc', 'kco')

for (i in df[dep]) {
    paste('m_', i) <- lm(i ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = df)
}
```

However the following error message is displayed:

```
Error in paste("m_", i) <- lm(i ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = dlc) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

How can I solve this problem?

What I want to avoid is to write the same model many times.

```
m_dlco <- lm(dlco ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = df)

m_dlno <- lm(dlno ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = df)

m_va <- lm(va ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = df)

m_vc <- lm(vc ~ sex + age + height + bmi, data = df)

m_kco <- lm(kco~ sex + age + height + weight, data = df)
```

Thanks in advance